# Spring Boot Exception Handling -> Not Return Generic Exception

Tags: java, spring-boot, exception

I have a problem to return the ErrorDTO from Generic Exception.

When I send a request to http://localhost:8080/v1/locations with this response body shown below, I get this issue underneath GlobalExceptionHandler.

```
{
    "code" : "DELHI_IN_QWERTYUI", -> IT thows an error because of its length (length is 12)
    "city_name" : "New Delhi",
    "region_name" : "Delhi",
    "country_name" : "India",
    "country_code" : "IN",
    "enabled" : true
}
```

Here is the method defined in controller shown below?

```
@PostMapping
    public ResponseEntity<Location> addLocation(@RequestBody @Valid Location location) {
        Location addedLocation = service.add(location);
        URI uri = URI.create("/v1/locations/" + addedLocation.getCode());

        return ResponseEntity.created(uri).body(addedLocation);
    }
```

How can I fix the issue?

Here is the ErrorDTO below.

```
@Builder
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class ErrorDTO {

    private LocalDateTime timestamp;
    private int status;
    private String path;
    private HttpStatus httpStatus;
    List<String> errorDetails;

}
```

Here is the GlobalExceptionError shown below

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class GlobalExceptionHandler extends ResponseEntityExceptionHandler {

    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(GlobalExceptionHandler.class);

    // handleMissingServletRequestParameter : triggers when there are missing parameters
    @Override
    protected ResponseEntity<Object> handleHttpRequestMethodNotSupported(HttpRequestMethodNotSupportedException ex, HttpHeaders headers, HttpStatusCode status, WebRequest request) {

        List<String> details = new ArrayList<String>();
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        builder.append(ex.getMessage() + " is not supported");
        details.add(builder.toString());

        HttpStatus httpStatus = HttpStatus.valueOf(status.value());

        ErrorDTO error = new ErrorDTO.ErrorDTOBuilder()
                .timestamp(LocalDateTime.now())
                .status(status.value())
                .errorDetails(details)
                .path(request.getContextPath())
                .httpStatus(httpStatus)
                .build();

        LOGGER.error("GlobalExceptionHandler | handleHttpRequestMethodNotSupported", error);

        return ResponseEntity.status(status).body(error);

    }

    // handleMethodArgumentNotValid : triggers when @Valid fails
    @Override
    protected ResponseEntity<Object> handleMethodArgumentNotValid(MethodArgumentNotValidException ex, HttpHeaders headers, HttpStatusCode status, WebRequest request) {
        Map<String, String> errors = new HashMap<>();
        ex.getBindingResult().getFieldErrors().forEach(err -> errors.put(err.getField(), err.getDefaultMessage()));

        LOGGER.error("GlobalExceptionHandler | handleMethodArgumentNotValid", errors);

        return ResponseEntity.badRequest()
                .body(errors);
    }

    // handleMissingServletRequestParameter : triggers when there are missing parameters
    @Override
    protected ResponseEntity<Object> handleMissingServletRequestParameter(MissingServletRequestParameterException ex, HttpHeaders headers, HttpStatusCode status, WebRequest request) {


        List<String> details = new ArrayList<String>();
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        builder.append(ex.getParameterName());
        details.add(builder.toString());

        HttpStatus httpStatus = HttpStatus.valueOf(status.value());

        ErrorDTO error = new ErrorDTO.ErrorDTOBuilder()
                .timestamp(LocalDateTime.now())
                .status(status.value())
                .errorDetails(details)
                .path(request.getContextPath())
                .httpStatus(httpStatus)
                .build();

        LOGGER.error("GlobalExceptionHandler | handleMissingServletRequestParameter", error);

        return ResponseEntity.status(status).body(error);

    }

    // handleHttpMessageNotReadable : triggers when the JSON is malformed
    @Override
    protected ResponseEntity<Object> handleHttpMessageNotReadable(HttpMessageNotReadableException ex, HttpHeaders headers, HttpStatusCode status, WebRequest request) {

        List<String> details = new ArrayList<String>();
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        builder.append(ex.getMessage());
        details.add(builder.toString());

        HttpStatus httpStatus = HttpStatus.valueOf(status.value());

        ErrorDTO error = new ErrorDTO.ErrorDTOBuilder()
                .timestamp(LocalDateTime.now())
                .status(status.value())
                .errorDetails(details)
                .path(request.getContextPath())
                .httpStatus(httpStatus)
                .build();

        LOGGER.error("GlobalExceptionHandler | handleHttpMessageNotReadable", error);

        return ResponseEntity.status(status).body(error);

    }


    @ExceptionHandler(Exception.class)
    public ErrorDTO handleGenericException(HttpServletRequest request, Exception ex) {

        List<String> details = new ArrayList<String>();
        details.add(ex.getMessage());

        ErrorDTO error = new ErrorDTO.ErrorDTOBuilder()
                .timestamp(LocalDateTime.now())
                .status(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR.value())
                .errorDetails(details)
                .path(request.getServletPath())
                .httpStatus(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR)
                .build();

        LOGGER.error("GlobalExceptionHandler | handleGenericException", error);

        return error;
    }
}
```

Here is the error shown below.

```
{
    "timestamp": "2023-02-17T12:56:02.341+00:00",
    "status": 404,
    "error": "Not Found",
    "trace": "org.springframework.dao.DataIntegrityViolationException: could not execute statement; SQL [n/a]\r\n\tat org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.convertHibernateAccessException(HibernateJpaDialect.java:273)\r\n\tat org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.translateExceptionIfPossible(HibernateJpaDialect.java:233)\r\n\tat org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager.doCommit(JpaTransactionManager.java:566)\r\n\tat org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.processCommit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:743)\r\n\tat org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.commit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:711)\r\n\tat org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.commitTransactionAfterReturning(TransactionAspectSupport.java:654)\r\n\tat org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:407)\r\n\tat org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:119)\r\n\tat org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:184)\r\n\tat org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:752)\r\n\tat org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:703)\r\n\tat com.skyapi.weatherforecast.location.LocationService$$SpringCGLIB$$0.add(<generated>)\r\n\tat com.skyapi.weatherforecast.location.LocationApiController.addLocation(LocationApiController.java:21)\r\n\tat java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:104)\r\n\tat java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:578)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:207)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:152)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:117)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:884)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:797)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1080)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:973)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1011)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:914)\r\n\tat jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:885)\r\n\tat jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:814)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:223)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:158)\r\n\tat org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:185)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:158)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:185)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:158)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:185)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:158)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:185)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:158)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:177)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:97)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:542)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:119)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:78)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:357)\r\n\tat org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:400)\r\n\tat org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65)\r\n\tat org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:859)\r\n\tat org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1734)\r\n\tat org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:52)\r\n\tat org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191)\r\n\tat org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659)\r\n\tat org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)\r\n\tat java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1589)\r\nCaused by: org.hibernate.exception.DataException: could not execute statement\r\n\tat org.hibernate.exception.internal.SQLExceptionTypeDelegate.convert(SQLExceptionTypeDelegate.java:53)\r\n\tat org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:56)\r\n\tat org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:109)\r\n\tat org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:95)\r\n\tat org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.executeUpdate(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:200)\r\n\tat org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3429)\r\n\tat org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:4058)\r\n\tat org.hibernate.action.internal.EntityInsertAction.execute(EntityInsertAction.java:103)\r\n\tat org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:612)\r\n\tat org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.lambda$executeActions$1(ActionQueue.java:483)\r\n\tat java.base/java.util.LinkedHashMap.forEach(LinkedHashMap.java:729)\r\n\tat org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:480)\r\n\tat org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractFlushingEventListener.performExecutions(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:329)\r\n\tat org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultFlushEventListener.onFlush(DefaultFlushEventListener.java:39)\r\n\tat org.hibernate.event.service.internal.EventListenerGroupImpl.fireEventOnEachListener(EventListenerGroupImpl.java:107)\r\n\tat org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.doFlush(SessionImpl.java:1425)\r\n\tat org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.managedFlush(SessionImpl.java:477)\r\n\tat org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.flushBeforeTransactionCompletion(SessionImpl.java:2234)\r\n\tat org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.beforeTransactionCompletion(SessionImpl.java:1930)\r\n\tat org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcCoordinatorImpl.beforeTransactionCompletion(JdbcCoordinatorImpl.java:439)\r\n\tat org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.beforeCompletionCallback(JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:183)\r\n\tat org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl$TransactionDriverControlImpl.commit(JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:281)\r\n\tat org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.TransactionImpl.commit(TransactionImpl.java:101)\r\n\tat org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager.doCommit(JpaTransactionManager.java:562)\r\n\t... 58 more\r\nCaused by: com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.MysqlDataTruncation: Data truncation: Data too long for column 'code' at row 1\r\n\tat com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLExceptionsMapping.translateException(SQLExceptionsMapping.java:104)\r\n\tat com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ClientPreparedStatement.executeInternal(ClientPreparedStatement.java:916)\r\n\tat com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ClientPreparedStatement.executeUpdateInternal(ClientPreparedStatement.java:1061)\r\n\tat com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ClientPreparedStatement.executeUpdateInternal(ClientPreparedStatement.java:1009)\r\n\tat com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ClientPreparedStatement.executeLargeUpdate(ClientPreparedStatement.java:1320)\r\n\tat com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ClientPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(ClientPreparedStatement.java:994)\r\n\tat com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.ProxyPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(ProxyPreparedStatement.java:61)\r\n\tat com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariProxyPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(HikariProxyPreparedStatement.java)\r\n\tat org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.executeUpdate(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:197)\r\n\t... 77 more\r\n",
    "message": "could not execute statement; SQL [n/a]",
    "path": "/v1/locations"
}
```

Here is the console output shown

```
org.springframework.web.HttpMediaTypeNotAcceptableException: No acceptable representation
```

It return this kind of exception message rather than ErrorDTO.

Here is the repo : [Link](https://github.com/Rapter1990/WeatherApiProject)

How can I fix the issue?

Comment: you can fix the issue by reading the exception, you have a problem with your SQLDialect, but you havn't shown that part of your code.

Comment: @Toerktumlare handleGenericException is normally called but it couldn't return ErrorDTO.

Comment: well its kindof hard when you have neither shown your full request including headers, and you have removed all the information in the stack trace. Why you dont include all the error information when you are seeking help is just strange to me

Comment: @Toerktumlare I shared the error. I also shared the method of the controller.

Comment: @Toerktumlare I also shared my repo. Can you look through it if you don't mind?

Comment: I didnt ask for the controller, and you didnt share the full stacktrace, read my comment again which you clearly didnt. Good luck im leaving

Comment: @Toerktumlare I already fixed the issue before your comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After adding `@Data` annotation to ErrorDTO, the issue disappeared.

```
@Builder
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Data
public class ErrorDTO {

    private LocalDateTime timestamp;
    private int status;
    private String path;
    private HttpStatus httpStatus;
    List<String> errorDetails;

}
```